# Informatica Connectivity with Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm trying to connect source as Mongo db to Informatica 9.1 power center using Simba ODBC driver for Mongo db but I'm getting this error.

> DLL name entry missing from
>   c:\informatica\9.0.1\clients\PowerCenterClien\client\bin\powrmart.ini 
>   section = ODBCDLL Entry = TEXT

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making an entry in the powermart.ini file for the Simba DLL.

Comment: it will be similar to the existing entries. ODBC driver name=DLL File Name

Answer (score -1):

Add a `TEXT` entry in the `powermart.ini` file:

```
[ODBCDLL]
TEXT=EXTODBC.DLL
```